# Django error occurs while saving data fetched from Twitter api into database; TypeError: get_serializer() got an unexpected keyword argument "many"

Tags: python, django, database, api

I am trying to save data from Twitter API. While doing so,

> TypeError: get_serializer() got an unexpected keyword argument "many"

error occurs. I think it is due to calling too MANY `get_serializer()`
The below is how I fetch data from Twitter API

## view.py

```
for statusNEAR in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='#NYU', geocode="40.72942,-73.99721,1km").items(1):
json_dataNEAR = (statusNEAR._json)

nearTEXT_data = json_dataNEAR['text']
nearNAME_data = json_dataNEAR['user']['name']
nearUSERNAME_data = json_dataNEAR['user']['screen_name']
nearLOCATION_data = json_dataNEAR['user']['location']


class TweetListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
model = Tweet

def get_serializer(self):
    return TweetSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    return Tweet.objects.all()

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.DATA)



    if not serializer.is_valid():
        return Response(
            serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        tweet = Tweet.objects.create(
            type= 'near',
            text = context['near']['text'],
            name = context['near']['name'],
            username = context['near']['username'],
            location = context['near']['location'],

            month = context['near']['month'],
            day = context['near']['day'],
            hour = context['near']['hour'],
            min = context['near']['min'],
            year = context['near']['year'],
            retweet = context['near']['retweet'],
            favorite = context['near']['favorite'],
            img = context['near']['imgurl']
    )
    result = TweetSerializer(tweet)
    return Response(result.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

## serializers.py

```
class TweetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Tweet
    fields = ('type', 'text', 'name', 'username',
                'location', 'month', 'day', 'min',
                'year','retweet','favorite','img')
```

Images are attached for the details

[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNUgK.png)

[How I try to save data into database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e9fS.png)

Comment: You should copy and paste the error code into your question instead, it helps other from finding your question when they have the same error.

Comment: post the full stacktrace and the TweetSerializer

Comment: You should show the code for TweetSerializer.